# Синтаксис php

Tags: php

Я так понял, что вообще необязательно в суперглобальных массивах имя переменной заключать в кавычки. И без кавычек работает

```
$_POST[user]
```

Какие комментарии по этому поводу?

Comment: Это некорректно, хотя бы потому, что "user" может оказаться константой.

В этом случае при `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`, "вылезут" Notice-ы.

Comment: это не имя переменной, а ключ массива. Всегда включайте в кавычки.

Comment: Именно за такие возможности php угадывать желания программиста, его любят начинающие ненавидят другие. Другое дело, что иногда угадывает совсем не так, как ожидается.

Comment: ReinRaus - 
Это неверно, хотя и работает. Причина в том, что этот код содержит неопределенную константу (bar), а не строку ('bar' - обратите внимание на кавычки), и PHP в будущем может определить константу, которая, к несчастью для вашего кода, будет иметь то же самое имя.

Как пхп может в будущем определить константу, если я самолично не попрошу его об этом???

Comment: > Deonis, на локалке работают русскоязычные переменные

Да пусть себе работают сколько угодно, главное, чтоб не на хостинге. А то какому-то умнику придет мысль в голову писать на фарси или идише и по закону подлости, вам придется редактировать его код. ))

Comment: Ну, спор-то утих? )) У меня define однозначно имеют другое имя (тем более пишу их в верхнем регистре). Не получен ответ на вопрос - можно ли  ? А если нельзя - то : почему?

Comment: Можно. Дуракам всё можно.

Comment: klop, я слабоумный, поэтому и задаю здесь вопросы

Comment: @Deus, проблема не в том, что задаете вопросы, а в том, что не слушаете ответы. На стройке всегда работают в касках, но это же не значит, что нельзя, верно?

Answer (score 6):

В кавычках - всегда, потому что, например:

```
<?php
define( user, '127.0.0.1' );
echo user;
echo $_POST[user];
?>
```

Вместо user, понятное дело, может быть что угодно, и задефайнено где угодно до нашего кода

Comment: Короче, конкретного ответа нет. Будто кавычки созданы, чтобы отделить константы от других наименований ключей массива, что-ли? Если я буду использовать суперглобальные массивы без кавычек, будет ли код валидным???

Comment: И вообще, при использовании кириллицы(символов русского алфавита) для объявления переменных, код тоже работает. Будет ли он работать в глобальной сети, или же только в Денвере?

Comment: @Deus, Синтаксической ошибкой это не будет, но лично с моей точки зрения - код не валидный. Привычка - вещь опасная и в будущем может сыграть с вами злую шутку. Поэтому, сто раз побумайте перед тем, как брать такой синтаксис за основу.

По поводу кириллицы - даже и не знаю, что ответить, но глаза от удивления у меня округлились.

Comment: @Deus, конктерный ответ есть: набирать кавычки.

Comment: define( user, '127.0.0.1' );
    echo user;

> Use of undefined constant user -
> assumed 'user'

php 5.3.3 не хавает константы в нижнем регистре?

Comment: А не пофиг? Это всего лишь демонстрация кривости подхода в принципе.

Comment: @Palmervan, хавает, но первый параметр у ``define`` - строка, т.е. ``define('user'..``

Comment: Чёта я тупанул) My apologies)

Comment: Deonis, на локалке  работают русскоязычные переменные

Comment: Ребята, я просил ответа  стандарт ДОПУСКАЕТ отсутствие кавычек ИЛИ НЕТ?

Comment: Ты ж вроде не совсем слабоумный, стандарт можешь и сам прочитать.

Answer (score -2):

Замечание: Это не означает, что нужно всегда заключать ключ в кавычки. Нет необходимости заключать в кавычки константы или переменные, поскольку это помешает PHP обрабатывать их. [пхп.нет](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)